# new refiner in peopleresults.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-search, refiner

I followed this guide to add a refiner for peopleresults.aspx
http://nikcharlebois.com/creating-custom-search-refiners-in-office-365-using-term-sets/

The idea is that there is a list where a taxonomy/metadata field from the term store that accepts multiple values is matched with a user.

The property is mapped correctly so that a content search web part displays correctly the refinablestring01 content.

The refiner in peopleresults.aspx does not give any result. The only difference I have with the guide above is that my value is multiple choice instead of single choice.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the refiner results in results.aspx page? In the Refinement web part, whether there is value in the Sample value section for RefinableString00 managed property?

[image]

Per my knowledge, the managed metadata column is crawled under the “Everything” content source which doesn’t include People, hence, in the peopleresults.aspx page, there is no value for this managed property.

Comment: so if i change type of column (from managed metadata to free text or choice, can i get my result in peopleresults? or there is no way to add a refiner of this kind on this page?